# Providing a reference with nested functions in js

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to provide a reference to a function of 1st js in 2nd js. I am aware of single functions and passing variables etc. However, how do I give reference to a function within another function?

HTML

```
...
...
<script src="./js/scripts.js">
  </script>
  <script src="./js/pure-swipe.js">
  </script>
```

scripts.js

```
@param {HTMLElement} element The Element
var Application = function(element) {
        this.init();
    };
    Application.prototype = {
      onClickNext: function() {
            this.goToNext();
        }
     goToNext: function() {
            console.log("NEXT");
        },
};

window.addEventListener("load", function() {
        var elements = Utility.toArray(document.querySelectorAll(Utility.selector("application")));
        for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
            var instance = new Application(elements[i]);
        }
    });
```

pure-swipe.js

```
    document.addEventListener('swiped-left', function(e) {
       
            onClickNext(); //Call function here

        // ...
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attach the reference to the global object (which, in the browser, is `window`)

In the code below, I have changed `var instance` to `window.instance`. This allows you to access it in `pure-swipe.js` by using `window.instance.onClickNext()`

```
// scripts.js
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
        var elements = Utility.toArray(document.querySelectorAll(Utility.selector("application")));
        for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
            window.instance = new Application(elements[i]);
        }
    });

// pure-swipe.js
document.addEventListener('swiped-left', function(e) {
    window.instance.onClickNext(); //Call function here
});
```

Comment: I am sorry I don't follow it. What exactly should i give reference to? The function or the application.prototype? Could you please show me with an example ? thanks

Comment: @Saif - show your code - where do you create a new `Application`.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks alot. So just had to add window to the instance. But is there a reason behind it? I mean why not just access the variable instance directly?

Comment: @Saif because they are in separate files. The code in the files cannot talk to each other directly - `pure-swipe.js` hsa no idea what variables are declared in `scripts.js` but they are executed in the same context (the global browser context). So as long as you make a reference available in a context that both files can read - e.g. by attaching references to the `window` object - then they can "talk" to each other.

Answer (score 1):

In this particular example, you'll need an object created via `new Application` (or similar), which will have `onClickNext` on it as an inherited property. So if you have that object referenced from the variable `app`, for instance, then:

```
document.addEventListener('swiped-left', function(e) {
   
        app.onClickNext(); //Call function here

    // ...
});
```

The function is also accessible as `Application.prototype.onClickNext` but it's clearly meant to be used as a method, not directly. (Technically, with the code you've shown, it would work if you called it directly, but I assume the content of `goToNext` is more complex than just a `console.log`. In any case, directly calling `Application.prototype.onClickNext` would be very poor practice without supplying it a valid `this` to use.)

Comment: I tried with Application.prototype.onClickNext but it was not getting called. As in Application is not defined error.